# cannot find libx11 - are libx11 and libX11 the same?

Tags: c, installation, build, x11

I am trying to build a program that needs me to specify where the libx11 is installed. I do not own administrator privileges but I asked the responsible to install al packages containing x11 like libx11-dev and else. However, I cannot find the libx11 libraries  using the locate command, only libX11 (note the capitalisation difference). Are they the same thing? If not, how can I get libx11? I am asking this because when I specify the libX11 I still get errors. The library is specified as a pointer like this:

```
LIBNCARG=-L$(NCARG_DIR)/lib  -lX11 -lncarg -lncarg_gks -lncarg_c -L/usr/lib -ldl -lpng -lpthread -lgfortran
```

The errors are the following (they repeat for different functions):

```
/p1-nemo/danilocs/anaconda3/envs/ncl_stable/lib/libncarg_gks.a(pixoutput.o): In function `PIX_FillArea':
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xab0): undefined reference to `XFillPolygon'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xb09): undefined reference to `XCreatePixmap'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xb5b): undefined reference to `XSetFunction'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xb8a): undefined reference to `XFillPolygon'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xb9e): undefined reference to `XSetFunction'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xbdd): undefined reference to `XDrawLines'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xbf5): undefined reference to `XDrawLines'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xc32): undefined reference to `XDrawLine'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xc7f): undefined reference to `XDrawLine'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xcaa): undefined reference to `XDrawLine'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xcbe): undefined reference to `XSetStipple'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xcce): undefined reference to `XSetFillStyle'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xced): undefined reference to `XFillPolygon'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xcfa): undefined reference to `XSetFillStyle'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xd09): undefined reference to `XFreePixmap'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xd4b): undefined reference to `XDrawLine'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xd79): undefined reference to `XDrawLine'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xe2c): undefined reference to `XQueryBestStipple'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xe4b): undefined reference to `XCreateGC'
pixoutput.c:(.text+0xe80): undefined reference to `XFreePixmap'
```

Which I searched beforehand here and should be solved specifying the -lx11 pointer during the install procedure. But when I do change -lX11 for lx11 I get the error that lx11 cannot be found.

Any suggestions here are much appreciated.

Comment: `-lX11 -lncarg -lncarg_gks -lncarg_c` -> `-lncarg -lncarg_gks -lncarg_c -lX11`

Comment: On a case-sensitive file system, the file names `libX11.so` and `libx11.so` are not equivalent.  The conventional names for the main X11 library are variations on the former.  But that does not mean that on some particular system, libraries have been named differently.  In particular, you might get into a situation like that if a case-insensitive file system is involved somewhere.

Comment: The library names have capital X, but at least for Debian, the package names have lower case x.

Comment: So, I tried KamilCuk suggestion but the error persists...

For the others that mentioned the problem with case sensitive systems, which would be the solution? I used apt-get for the library but it would only install the capital X library

Thanks for the answers!